# Can't normally lock landscape orientation on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, screen-orientation

I'm using Screen Orientation API (https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/) for JavaScript.
I have the following problem: 
When I turn iPhone to landscape position (when button is on the left, selfie-cam on the right) it rotates screen normally, but after I invoke `screen.orientation.lock('landscape')`, it rotates screen and show screen upside-down.
It doesn't happen on android. On android when invoking `screen.orientation.lock('landscape')`, screen stays on landscape mode, as expected.
Could you please say, how this can be potentially fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that it is known problem of Screen Orientation API.
It's even mentioned in github of its library: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/issues/42 and the issue is still open.
So in my case, I just locked orientation to the current landscape, e.g. if it's 'landscape-secondary', then I use `screen.orientation.lock('landscape-primary')`. Why 'primary'? Because it mixed up, and if you are now on landscape-secondary and lock on landscape-secondary, then it will anyway rotate to landscape-primary.
So the answer is that it's the library issue.